# How can I get the values of Array which Nested in a JSON values and the JSON also nested in a Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

**How can I get the values of Array which Nested in a JSON values and the JSON also nested in a Array?**

```js
var contacts = [
  {
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];


var firstName = "Akira", prop = "likes";

for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  var a;
  console.log("contacts[i].firstName = " + contacts[i].firstName);
  if(contacts[i].firstName == firstName){
    a = true;
  } else {
    a = false;
  }
  // get the values of likes?
  // console.log("contacts[i].prop[i].value() = " + contacts[i].prop[i].value() );
  console.log("contacts[i][prop].value() = " + contacts[i][prop].value() );
}
```

if I want to get the value of likes & "firstName": "Akira", what should I do?
Anybody can help?

### solution

```js
var contacts = [
  {
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];


function getValuesByProps(firstName = "Akira", prop = "likes") {
  var result;
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if(contacts[i].firstName === firstName){
      console.log("contacts[i][prop] = " + contacts[i][prop]);
      result = contacts[i][prop];
      break;
    } 
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Your code seems ok. Where you have `a = true`, you can just go `contacts[i].likes` or `contacts[i][prop]` to get the array.

Comment: https://github.com/gildata/RAIO/issues/61

Answer (score 0):

The objects in the `contacts` array do not have a property whose name is `prop`. Fortunately, you can access properties on an object by name similar to how you would get a value out of an array, so if you use `contacts[i][prop]` it will get you the value of the property whose name is the value of the variable `prop`, which in this case is `"likes"`. Since `likes` is also an array, you would then get values out of it by indexing the same way you are indexing the `contacts` array.

```
var firstName = "Akira", prop = "likes";
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    var a;
    console.log("contacts[" + i + "].firstName = " + contacts[i].firstName);
    if (contacts[i].firstName == firstName){
        a = true;
    } else {
        a = false;
    }

    // get the likes array and loop through to print the values
    // you might want to put this where a = true; is if you only want to get 
    // the likes where the firstName matches
    var likes = contacts[i][prop];
    for (var j = 0; j < likes.length; j++) {
        console.log("contacts[" + i + "]." + prop + "[" + j + "] = " + likes[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoo might do as follows;

```js
var contacts = [
        {
            "firstName": "Akira",
            "lastName": "Laine",
            "number": "0543236543",
            "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Harry",
            "lastName": "Potter",
            "number": "0994372684",
            "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Sherlock",
            "lastName": "Holmes",
            "number": "0487345643",
            "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Kristian",
            "lastName": "Vos",
            "number": "unknown",
            "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
        }
    ],
  getMeObj = (d,p,v,t) => d.filter(o => o[p] === v)[0][t];
  console.log(getMeObj(contacts,"firstName", "Akira", "likes"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work

```js
/*

var firstName = "Akira", prop = "likes";

for(var i in contacts) {
  if(contacts[i].firstName === firstName){
    var likes = contacts[i][prop];
    console.log(likes);
  }
}

*/

let firstName = "Akira", prop = "likes";

for(let item of contacts) {
  if(item.firstName === firstName){
    const likes = item[prop];
    console.log(likes);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code. if you need more details ask me but I think the code is simple enough

```
var contacts = [{
  "firstName": "Akira",
  "lastName": "Laine",
  "number": "0543236543",
  "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Harry",
  "lastName": "Potter",
  "number": "0994372684",
  "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Sherlock",
  "lastName": "Holmes",
  "number": "0487345643",
  "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Kristian",
  "lastName": "Vos",
  "number": "unknown",
  "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}];
var firstName = "Akira"
  , prop = "likes";
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  var a;
  console.log("contacts[" + i + "].firstName = " + contacts[i].firstName);
  if (contacts[i].firstName == firstName) {
    a = true;
  } else {
    a = false;
  }
  for (var n = 0; n < contacts[i].likes.length; n++) {
    console.log("contacts[" + i + "].likes[" + n + "] = " + contacts[i].likes[n]);
  }
}
```

As a side note:answers should be in the same level of the asker to help with learning :)

Comment: The question appears to be asking how to get a property when all you have is a variable with the name of the property in it, in this case `var prop = "likes"`. This answer is getting the `likes` property directly without using the variable `prop`, so I'm not sure if it actually answers the question. (just an assumption that I and several others have made. It could very well be that you are the one who answered what is actually being asked)